# More friendly windows switcher as windows has

Tags: gnome

I'm looking a gnome extension (or anything) that can do the same like on windows the alt + tab both look and feel and more importantly ergonomics (I've already set back the hotkey on gnome to switch between windows).

It needs to know:

- alt + tab between windows selecting next window
- alt + shift + tab between windows selecting next window in reverse (backwards)
- while holding alt be able to use the arrows keys to navigate
- if there's a lot of windows opened, break it even into multiple lines so I see more windows than in the current version
- windows names should be under or above the window picture (you look there not to the middle of the screen...)
- be able to close with mouse the windows from that location
- selecting a window to be active by release alt, click on it or press space while it's focused.

Comment: Sounds like Gnome 2

Answer (score 1):

I have had a play in KDE plasma (the one I use). I can do most of this with out installing any extra plugins (plasma has lots of plugins).

The only bits that it did not do (so may be a plugin, or other config is needed) are: space to select, close with mouse.

For breaking it up. You can have two sets of short cut with different configuration. Configurations included

- desktop: same, other, both
- activity: same, other, both
- screen: same, other, both
- minimised: same, other, both
- include "show desktop"
- only one window per application

You can also set short cuts for rotating in the same application (with same options).

In other settings you can set a short-cut for send window to back. This has the effect or rotating through windows on same desktop and activity that are not minimised (but with no additional info displayed: just do it). I use this one most of the time.

Comment: ahh yeah, KDE plasma... I have no clue if there is dual GPU support there... (I'm using Pop OS because there is something, even if not the best.)